# search large files for special characters

Tags: search, text, automation, automated-tests, flat-file

One of the data validation steps that we perform is related to 'special characters' in output files.  These are text files, pipe delimited.  Today, we open the file in UltraEdit and then do a Ctrl+F.  These output files range in size, with the largest being over 54GB.  Looking for a more efficient (aka automated) approach to this step. Any suggestions?

Comment: Run UltraEdit with the command line options `/fni` and `/M` or `/S` with a macro or script created by you to run a replace in files on the large file without opening it in UltraEdit at all for maximum performance (no line counting, no undo recording, no highlighting, no window updates, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using java 
for 15gb file it took 30sec.

```
long found = Files.lines(Paths.get("dummy.txt"))
                 .filter(s -> s.contains("test"))
                 .count();
System.out.println(count);
```